# Optimization problem - maximizing number of satisfied linear inequalities subject to quadratic constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am wondering if anything is known about optimization problems of the following type.

Our control $x$ is a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We are given a finite number of linear inequalities
$$A z \geq b,$$
and we would like to select $x$ so that when substituted in place of $z$ the largest number of such inequalities is satisfied.

Any ideas or references to literature would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks similar to [support vector machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), the soft margin variant.

Comment: What is the quadratic constraint?

Comment: $x$ is a unit vector: $x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2=1$